# Selecting tab with custom lightning component, changing new winter 17 navigation colors

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I am testing my org on a winter 17 sandbox.

The new navigation system is great:

[image: standard navigation]

All works fine, except:

When I look at my custom object with the tabs component, I look at a tab with a standard component - all is ok, but when I choose a tab with a custom component that I have developed - the standard top navigation bar changes it's colors:

[image: custom changed colors]

After that happens, my navigation colors stay with this ugly change forever.

Does anyone know if I am doing something wrong (it happens with all of my components)?

Is it a bug?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the problem.

In winter 17 you do not need to add slds as a static resource:

For apps you need to add: extends="force:slds" in your aura:application.

And for components - you need to remove the ltng:require of the slds.

the coloring error appears when the slds is included (probably because of duplicate css...)